# Transparent comparator code minimization

Tags: c++, c++14

Let's say we store a struct with a string key and we want to find it by that string in a container like `std::set`, so common implementation would look like this:

```
struct Foo {
    std::string id;
};

struct FooComp {
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;

    bool operator()( const Foo &foo, const std::string &str ) const
    {
        return foo.id < str;
    }

    bool operator()( const std::string &str, const Foo &foo ) const
    {
        return str < foo.id;
    }

    bool operator()( const Foo &foo1, const Foo &foo2 ) const
    {
        return foo1.id < foo2.id;
    }
};

 std::set<Foo,FooComp> foo_set;
 ...
```

This works fine, but writing three methods for `FooComp` that do prety match the same (logically) is monotonic and error prone. Is there a way to minimize that code?

Comment: using a template? (just a random guess :)

Comment: @Slava  It is enough to declare a conversion constructor for the structure.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but that would have overhead for non trivial struct `Foo` right? So this is not exactly equal solution. Of course it does not mean this is not one of solutions. Probably you should make that an answer.

Comment: @user1810087 most probably yes and question is here to get a reusable solution that can be valuable for everybody. If it is possible of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may do as following:

```
struct Foo {
    std::string id;
};

struct FooComp {
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;

    template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
    bool operator()(const LHS& lhs, const RHS& rhs) const
    {
        return ProjectAsId(lhs) < ProjectAsId(rhs);
    }

private:
    const std::string& ProjectAsId(const std::string& s) const { return s; }
    const std::string& ProjectAsId(const Foo& foo) const { return foo.id; }
};
```

You write comparison once, but you have to write the projection for each type.

In C++17, it can even be

```
template <auto f> struct ProjLess
{
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;

    template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
    bool operator()(const LHS& lhs, const RHS& rhs) const
    {
        return project(lhs) < project(rhs);
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    using f_t = decltype(std::invoke(f, std::declval<const T&>()));

    template <typename T>
    using is_f_callable = is_detected<f_t, T>;

    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_f_callable<T>::value>* = nullptr>
    decltype(auto) project(const T& t) const { return std::invoke(f, t); }

    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_f_callable<T>::value>* = nullptr>
    const T& project(const T& t) const { return t; }
};
```

And usage:

```
std::set<Foo, ProjLess<&Foo::id>> s;
```

[Demo with C++17](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cacf99ca682434b9)

Comment: Seems that there is a typo `return ProjectAsId(lhs) < ProjectAsId(lhs);` must be `return ProjectAsId(lhs) < ProjectAsId(rhs);`

Comment: @cwschmidt: Indeed, fixed.

Comment: Great solution! Is there a way to make it more generic?

Comment: @Slava: Found a solution more generic. I use C++17 for usage `ProjLess<&Foo::id>` instead of `ProjLess<decltype(&Foo::id), &Foo::id>`.

Comment: I tried to use this approach but faced an issue with the usage: if a class has two overloaded functions `void f()` and `void f() const` the call is ambiguous and I really struggle to find any solution for it

Comment: @VladTkach: Usage is more verbose then: `ProjLess<static_cast<int (Foo::*)() const>(&Foo::id)>`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is all in the class:

```
struct FooComp {
  using is_transparent = std::true_type;
  struct FooProj {
    std::string const& str;
    FooProj( std::string const& sin ):str(sin) {}
    FooProj( const Foo& foo ):str(foo.id) {}
    FooProj( FooProj const& ) = default;
    friend bool operator<(FooProj lhs, FooProj rhs) {
      return lhs.str < rhs.str;
    }
  };
  bool operator()( FooProj lhs, FooProj rhs ) const
  {
    return lhs<rhs;
  }
};
```

This doesn't support types that can convert to `std::string`.

However, when doing a projection-based comparison, I do this:

```
template<class F, class After=std::less<>>
auto order_by( F&& f, After&& after={} ) {
  return
    [f=std::forward<F>(f), after=std::forward<After>(after)]
    (auto&& rhs, auto&&lhs)->bool {
      return after( f(decltype(lhs)(lhs)), f(decltype(rhs)(rhs)) );
    };
}
```

which takes a projection and generates a comparison function for it.  We make it transparent with:

```
template<class F>
struct as_transparent_t {
  F f;
  using is_transparent=std::true_type;
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  bool operator(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs)const{ return f(lhs, rhs); }
};
template<class F>
as_transparent_f<std::decay_t<F>>
as_transparent( F&& f ) { return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }
```

so we can project and be transparent via:

```
as_transparent( order_by( some_projection ) );
```

which only leaves the projection.

In C++14 we just do a

```
std::string const& foo_proj_f( std::string const& str ) { return str; }
std::string const& foo_proj_f( Foo const& foo ) { return foo.id; }
auto foo_proj = [](auto const& x)->decltype(auto){ return foo_proj_f(x); };
auto foo_order = as_transparent( order_by( foo_proj ) );
```

which breaks things down into modular chunks.

In C++17 we can use `if constexpr`:

```
auto foo_proj = [](auto const& x)->std::string const& {
  if constexpr( std::is_same<decltype(x), std::string const&>{} ) {
    return x;
  }
  if constexpr( std::is_same<decltype(x), Foo const&>{} ) {
    return x.id;
  }
};
auto foo_order = as_transparent( order_by( foo_proj ) );
```

or

```
template<class...Ts>
struct overloaded:Ts...{
  using Ts::operator()...;
  overloaded(Ts...ts):Ts(std::move(ts)...){}
};
template<class...Ts> overloaded -> overloaded<Ts...>;
```

which permits

```
auto foo_proj = overloaded{
  [](std::string const& s)->decltype(auto){return s;},
  [](Foo const& f)->decltype(auto){return f.id;}
};
```

which may be easier to read than the `if constexpr` version.  (This version can also be adapted to [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) or [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)).

Comment: `overloaded` (from [std::visit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)) is an alternative as `if constexpr`.